# basemapの『cyl projection cannot cross pole』のエラー対処方法

Tags: python, python3

## 直面している問題

取得したデータを地図上にプロットしたくbasemapのインストールを行いました。
インストールできていることを確認するため、単純に日本地図を描画するコードを実行したところ、『cyl projection cannot cross pole』というエラーが出ました。

## エラーメッセージ

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d7b0840e2c1b> in <module>()
      6 
      7 # Basemapの定義
----> 8 m = Basemap(llcrnrlat=south,urcrnrlat=north, llcrnrlon=west,urcrnrlon=east,resolution='h')
      9 # 海岸線を引く
     10 m.drawcoastlines()

C:\Users\9047247\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py in __init__(self, llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat, urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat, llcrnrx, llcrnry, urcrnrx, urcrnry, width, height, projection, resolution, area_thresh, rsphere, ellps, lat_ts, lat_1, lat_2, lat_0, lon_0, lon_1, lon_2, o_lon_p, o_lat_p, k_0, no_rot, suppress_ticks, satellite_height, boundinglat, fix_aspect, anchor, celestial, round, epsg, ax)
   1107         if self.resolution is not None:
   1108             self.coastsegs, self.coastpolygontypes =\
-> 1109             self._readboundarydata('gshhs',as_polygons=True)
   1110             # reformat for use in matplotlib.patches.Polygon.
   1111             self.coastpolygons = []

C:\Users\9047247\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py in _readboundarydata(self, name, as_polygons)
   1239         if containsPole and\
   1240             self.projection in _cylproj + _pseudocyl + ['geos']:
-> 1241             raise ValueError('%s projection cannot cross pole'%(self.projection))
   1242         # make sure some projections have has containsPole=True
   1243         # we will compute the intersections in stereographic

ValueError: cyl projection cannot cross pole
```

## 該当するコード

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import _geoslib
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# 緯度経度で範囲を指定する
north = 46.
south = 30.
east = 147.
west = 128.

# Basemapの定義
m = Basemap(llcrnrlat=south,urcrnrlat=north, llcrnrlon=west,urcrnrlon=east,resolution='h')
# 海岸線を引く
m.drawcoastlines()
```

## 前提

os  : windows(32bit)
 python : 3.6.1
 basemap: 1.1.0

basemapのインストールは http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ より該当するwhlファイルをダウンロードしてpipで行いました。
また、basemapの前提となるpyprojのインストールは、Anaconda Navigatorから行いました。
 （versionは1.9.5.1です）

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/104573

Answer (score 1):

自己解決したので以下に記載します。

結論
以下のコマンドでconda-forgeからinstallする。

conda install -c conda-forge basemap

condaからだと、win32+python3.6に適用したbasemapがなかったのであきらめていたのですが、上記を試したところエラーなくコードが動きました。